# I'm getting this error " Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" when i send a file to server using axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I'm getting this error " Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" when i send a file to server using axios. I don't know what is causing the error, i have tested the code on Postman and is working perfectly and sending the information from the contact to my database.

This is the full error am getting

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:62)
```

I don't know why the axios is not working.

This is the react code

```
const Contact_me = () => {
 
  const [contact, setContact] = useState({
    name:'',
    email:'',
    subject:'',
    message:''
  })

  const handleSubmit = (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault()
    if(!contact){
      console.log('invalid input')
    } else{
      const item = {
        name:contact.name,
        email:contact.email,
        subject:contact.subject,
        message:contact.message
      }
     axios.post('/contact/add', {item}) 
     
     .then(res => res.data)
     console.log('contact sent')
    }
  }
```

This is the backend code

```
const express = require('express')
const Contact = require('../model/contacts')

// express router object 
const router = express.Router()

// post router to recieve what the user has sent to me

router.post('/add', async(req, res)=>{
  const item = await new Contact({
    name : req.body.name,
    email : req.body.email,
    subject : req.body.subject,
    message : req.body.message,
  })
  try {
    const save_item = await item.save()
    res.json(save_item)
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(404).json(`error : ${error}`)
  }
})

module.exports = router
```

Comment: what is the error message you are getting?

Comment: This is the full error am getting "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:62)

Comment: use different method, the post method..

Comment: Please, i can't see your full message to me, i can only see "use different method, the post method ...."  please  help me understand what you are saying to me. I'm still stock here. I really don't know how to use this website properly.

Answer (score 1):

Have you previously setted any proxy on your react project? if you haven't, then you should specify the full path to your server api when fetching the data.

example: (replace the port with the one running your node app)

`axios.post('http://localhost:5000/contact/add')` instead of just `/contact/add`.

Comment: Yes i set a proxy but i even tried putting the full url but still, is not working. I don't know why. understanding axios is one of my major problem since i stated this journey few months ago.

Comment: Could you show us the exact url your react app is fetching to in the browser's network section?

Comment: ``` 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/contact/add' ``` this is the url am sending the data to.

Answer (score -1):

@Fliotta, i don't know if this is what you meant.

I have added the full url and deleted the Proxy

```
const [contact, setContact] = useState({
    name:'',
    email:'',
    subject:'',
    message:''
  })

  const handleSubmit = (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault()
    if(!contact){
      console.log('invalid input')
    } else{
      const item = {
        name:contact.name,
        email:contact.email,
        subject:contact.subject,
        message:contact.message
      }
     axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/contact/add', {item}) 
     
     .then(res => res.data)
     console.log('contact sent')
    }
  }
```